# HTTP Last-modified without ETag, Expires, Cache-Control?

Tags: http-caching

I want the clients to always check if the file has been modified. If it has: download from the server. If it has not: load it from cache. Is it advised to use Last-modified without ETag, Expires and Cache-Control headers?